# Função AJAX não passa o resultado para outra função

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-core

Possuo esta função em AJAX:

```js
function SalvarHorario() {


    //NomeHorario
    var nome = $("#Nome").val();

    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Horario/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var headers = {};
    var headersadr = {};
    headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
    headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

    //Gravar
    var url = "/Horario/Create";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: 'POST'
        , headers: headersadr
        , data: { Id: 0, Nome: nome, __RequestVerificationToken: token }
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.Resultado > 0) {
            ListarItens(data.Resultado);
            //    alert(data.Resultado);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

O Resultado está correto, está pegando o ID certo, porém ele não passa para a função ListarItens, já fiz assim em outros projetos, e funcionava bem, ele entende que não é maior que 0, sendo que no console, o Resultado pega o último ID inserido corretamente, como posso proceder? Ja tentei de várias formas, e nenhuma passa o ID correto.

Este é o listar itens:

```js
function ListarItens(idHorario) {

    var url = "/HorariosItens/ListarItens";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: idHorario }
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            var divItens = $("#divItens");
            divItens.empty();
            divItens.show();
            divItens.html(data);
            $("#idItem").val("0");
        }
    });

}
```

Onde eu preciso dessa função:

```js
 public ActionResult ListarItens(int id)
        {
            var lista = _context.HorariosItens.Where(m => m.Horarios.Id == id);
            ViewBag.HorarioId = id;
            ViewBag.ItemId = 0;
            return PartialView(lista);
        }
```

Creio que o problema esteja no data.Resultado, pois ele não está passando, se eu coloco um alert, ele me retorna undefined, porém é incluído com sucesso, tanto que ele passa do success: function (data).

Horário Create:

```js
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Horarios.Add(h);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return new JsonResult(new { Resultado = h.Id });
```

Comment: Poste o código de ListarItens.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Seria possível adicionar o código do `Horario/Create`?

Comment: Editado a pergunta, lembrando que ele salva no banco normal com a função.

Comment: Ficou um pouco confuso a explicação, eu entendi que ele insere normalmente, porém o retorno de data.Retorno é undefined?

Comment: Sim, ele insere normal, ai quando tem o if (data.Resultado > 0) { ele não entra, porém no console, ele mostra o valor do resultado correto.

Comment: Utilizando asp.net core e pages razors.

Comment: Não sei ao certo se pode ser isso, mas acredito que o problema está no retorno `JsonResult`. Mude o seu método para um `ActionResult` e no retorno um `return Json(new { Resultado = h.Id });`

Comment: Ele já está action result, quando coloco o Json ele retorna este erro.  O nome do tipo ou do namespace "Json" não pode ser encontrado (está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de assembly?)

Comment: Quando eu vejo no network do navegador, ele aparece {resultado: 278}, porém adicionei este código na função,  console.log(data.result);
            console.log(data.Resultado); e os dois aparecem undefined.

Comment: aaaah.. você que estava com problemas no retorno Json.. Então, Tem algo erro ai, esse código está em um `controller` né? o que esse `controller` está herdando?

Comment: Por favor, tente console.log(data.resultado) com o **R** minúsculo

Comment: Direto no navegador, ele me retorna o seguinte erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13 . O Create não está em um controller, os demais estão.

Comment: Não diretamente no navegador e sim na sua função. no navegador essa variável não existe mais, ou melhor, mude `ListarItens(data.Resultado);` para `ListarItens(data.resultado);` Não se esqueça do `ctrl+f5` para limpar o cache

Comment: @Barbetta agora no console ele aparece o id corretamente, e entra na função, porém public ActionResult ListarItens(int id) agora ele me retorna erro nesta função, nesta primeira linha. o ID está sendo passado.

Comment: @marianac_costa o erro na lista deve ser outro, porque não entra naquela função se não passar algum número

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78163/discussion-between-barbetta-and-marianac-costa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorreu porque por padrão os retornos de `json` no .NET Core são em *camel casing*, e a primeira letra é minúscula.

Uma forma de quebrar isso é no `Startup.cs` "informar" que deseja que o `json` seja como está escrito na variável. O código para isso seria:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

Outra solução, conforme comentado, é esperar que os retornas sejam em *camel casing*, ou seja, **Retorno** virá **retorno**

<sub>Você pode ver mais sobre *camel casing* [nesse link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/143304)</sub>